# Implementing Lazy Sorting algorithm using C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Our Professor gave us a programming exercise:

> Juan Tamad is a lazy person. He is tasked to sort a list of numbers,
>   but he is super lazy. He gets tired figuring out how to swap all the
>   numbers around until all of them are in increasing order. So, he came
>   up with his own algorithm that will guarantee that the new list is
>   sorted. Here's how it works:
>
> For a list of size n, we will need n-1 iterations. On each iteration,
>
> Check if the nth number is smaller that the n+1 th number. If it is,
>   then these two numbers are already sorted and we can skip this
>   iteration If they are not, we continually decrement the first n
>   numbers until these two numbers are in order.
>
> For example, suppose the input is
>
> ```
> 10 5 7 6 1
> ```
>
> On the first iteration, we compare 10 and 5. 10 is larger than 5 so we
>   decrement until its smaller:
>
> ```
> 4 5 7 6 1
> ```
>
> Now we compare 5 and 7. 5 is smaller than 7, so we do not need to do
>   anything and we skip this iteration. We go to the next and compare 7
>   and 6. 7 is larger than 6, so we decrement the first three numbers
>   until it's smaller than 6 and we get this:
>
> ```
> 2 3 5 6 1
> ```
>
> Now we compare 6 and 1. Again, 6 is larger than 1, so we decrement the
>   first four numbers until it's smaller than 1, and we get this:
>
> ```
> -4 -3 -1 0 1
> ```
>
> And we're done. Now the list is in perfect sorted order.
>
> Your assignment is to implement the sorting algorithm of Juan Tamad in
>   a C++ program. Your program reads an input n and the list of n
>   numbers. Your program them sorts the numbers using Juan Tamad's
>   algorithm.

So I wonder if someone can help maybe at least in articulating the problem.
So far my mind has produced:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

  int n;
  cin >> n;

  int a[n];

  for(int i = 0; i< n; i++)
  cin>> a[i];

  for(int i = 0; i< n; i++)
    cout<< a[i] << " ";

//______________________________________
  for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
    for(int j = i + 1; j < n-1; j++){
      if(a[i] > a[j])
        a[i]--;
      }

  }

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout << a[i] << " ";

  return 0;
}
```

Sample Runs:

```
$./a.out
Enter value of n: 5 
Enter 5 numbers: 10 5 7 6 1
Output: -4 -3 -1 0 1

$./a.out
Enter value of n: 10 
Enter 10 numbers: 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
Output: -8 - 7 - 6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1

$./a.out
Enter value of n: 6 
Enter 6 numbers: 1 2 3 1 2 3
Output: -2 -1 0 1 2 3

$./a.out
Enter value of n: 10
Enter 6 numbers: 5 7 11 6 16 2 9 16 6 16
Output: -27 -25 -21 -20 -10 -9 -2 5 6 16

$./a.out
Enter value of n: 1
Enter 6 numbers: 100
Output: 100
```

Comment: So what is your question? Is there something wrong with the code you have written so far?

Comment: yes sir , wrong output

Comment: sample runs: $./a.out
Enter value of n: 5 
Enter 5 numbers: 10 5 7 6 1
Output: -4 -3 -1 0 1

$./a.out
Enter value of n: 10 
Enter 10 numbers: 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
Output: -8 - 7 - 6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1

$./a.out
Enter value of n: 6 
Enter 6 numbers: 1 2 3 1 2 3
Output: -2 -1 0 1 2 3

$./a.out
Enter value of n: 10
Enter 6 numbers: 5 7 11 6 16 2 9 16 6 16
Output: -27 -25 -21 -20 -10 -9 -2 5 6 16

$./a.out
Enter value of n: 1
Enter 6 numbers: 100
Output: 100

Comment: I don't think anything related with your deadlines and your professor is relevant to the question. And also, as @MichaelHancock it is hard to see any question at all here.

Comment: I need someone who can explain the algorithm in newbies' terms ?

Comment: @mike, `int n;` followed by `int a[n];` is not legal C++, but a gcc extension.  You should use `vector` for this purpose. I would encourage you to attempt to work this problem by hand on paper and see what steps you are taking and think about how to translate that into code.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity will try. thanks

Comment: [mcve] please. Please give an example input together with the correct output and your program's wrong output.

Answer (score 0):

This is the super lazy implementation of the mentioned lazy algorithm: it has just `O(n)` complexity:

```
template <class It>
auto lazy_sort(It begin, It end) -> void
{
    auto rbegin = std::make_reverse_iterator(end);
    auto rend = std::make_reverse_iterator(begin);

    auto it = rbegin;
    if (it == rend)
        return;
    auto prev_val = *it;
    ++it;

    int diff = 0;

    for (; it != rend; ++it)
    {
        diff += std::max(0, *it - prev_val + 1);

        prev_val = *it;
        *it -= diff;
    }
}
```

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_lazy_sort)
{
    std::vector<int> v = {10, 5, 7, 6, 1};    

    lazy_sort(v.begin(), v.end());

    BOOST_CHECK((v == std::vector<int>{-4, -3, -1, 0, 1}));
}
```

Comment: (I almost missed *_reverse_*.)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some points for you:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
```

instead of going `[first, last)` I would go `(first, last]` this is because you need to look at the previous value. But your way works too.

```
for(int j = i + 1; j < n-1; j++)
```

here you go through the right of `i` unconditionally. This is wrong. You need to:

- first check if `v[i + 1] >= v[i]`. If not, the elements are in place. You can continue
- else. You need to decrement all elements `[first, i)`. For this the `for` should look like this:

  for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
- and you don't need to actual decrement by `1`. you can see the difference between the elements and then subtract. For instance when you encounter the elements `6 1` you need to subtract `6` (`6 - 1 + 1`) from all elements up until `i`.

The rest is up to you.